# Desplegar submenu al pasar el mouse sobre el LINK del menu

Tags: html5, css3

Buenas tardes, estoy comenzando a aprender HTML, en este caso estoy experimentando con los menu, y quisiera que se abra el submenu al pasar el mouse **sobre** el link de los menu.

Este es el menu desplegable que tengo ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las opciones "Lozas, Lapidas, Promociones, Fotos 20x30" se despliegan cuando paso el mouse **sobre** la lista(opción "Productos") mas no en el link que está dentro esa lista.

Entonces mi duda es como hacer para que se abra el submenu cuando pase el mouse **sobre** el link(`<a>`)

*Este es mi html:*

```
<nav>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="" class="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="prod"><a href="#" class="linkprod">Productos</a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Lozas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lápidas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fotos 20x30</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
            <li><a href="quienessomos.html">Quiénes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cómo se hace</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
```

*Y este es el css:*

```
  nav .menu {

   text-align: center;

   }

  nav .menu li{

   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 29px;
   list-style: none;

    }

  nav .menu li a{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;

    }


   nav .menu li a:hover{

      border-bottom: 2px solid #F13006;
      border-radius: 4px;

    }

   /*ACÁ COMIENZA CSS PARA SUBMENU*/

   .submenu{

    display: none;

    }


    .prod .linkprod:hover > ul{

    position: absolute;
    display: block;

   }
```

Entonces, para ser más especifico mi consulta seria; cómo hago para que el submenu se despliegue solamente cuando pase el mouse sobre el link, y también mi otro problema es que las listas de los submenus se están poniendo uno a lado de otro pero no debajo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tienes que usar el selector de hermanos '~' para que el hover en link de productos afecte al submenu

```css
nav .menu {

   text-align: center;

   }

  nav .menu li{

   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 29px;
   list-style: none;

    }

  nav .menu li a{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;

    }


   nav .menu li a:hover{

      border-bottom: 2px solid #F13006;
      border-radius: 4px;

    }

   /*ACÁ COMIENZA CSS PARA SUBMENU*/

   .submenu{
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .linkprod:hover ~ .submenu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="" class="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="prod"><a href="#" class="linkprod">Productos</a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="#">Lozas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lápidas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fotos 20x30</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
            <li><a href="quienessomos.html">Quiénes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cómo se hace</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
```

Tienes que usar el selector de hermanos '~' para que el hover en link de productos afecte al submenu

Comment: se desaparece el submenu y no se puede seleccionar

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer con la siguiente propiedad de css puedes omitir hacer referencia al `id` de tu submenu ya que con el codigo le estas indicando cuales elementos son los que va a desplegar al pasar el mouse.

```
.menu li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}
```

.menu hace referencia al el nombre de tu `clase` que encierra tus `li` con que formas tu menu.

Comment: Claro, al poner eso se abre el submenu correctamente, pero se abre cuando me acerco a la opción, lo que deseo hacer es que se abra recién cuando estoy con el mouse **encima** del link, encima de la palabra mejor dicho,